# MsTeams Bot: Error: BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(): 500 ERROR Error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: javascript, node.js, microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

We are getting the following error only in Pre Production environment but not in Local and develop. Does any one have idea on this, Please suggest a solution

````
[onTurnError] unhandled error: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
(node:24) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(): 500 ERROR
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
   at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1501:34)
   at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
   at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:936:8)
   at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:710:12)
   at BotFrameworkAdapter.<anonymous> (/home/deploy/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/botFrameworkAdapter.js:674:27)
   at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
   at rejected (/home/deploy/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/botFrameworkAdapter.js:12:65)
   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:24) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:24) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.```
````

Comment: (1) Looks like you see issue with your CA certs or due to the exception handling thrown but not handled with .catch(). (2) If its prior one then please note that the Messaging endpoint specified on the Settings page for your bot in the Bot Framework Portal does not begin with https or is not trusted by the Bot Framework. Your bot must have a valid, chain-trusted certificate. Make sure you have it (3) If its later then try do better exception handling at your end. Let me know how it goes

Comment: Does the above helped?

Comment: Are you still facing the issue ?